$(t-s)$ substitution in the derivation of Lindblad master equation
In the derivation of the Lindblad equation from first principles, on reaching the Redfield equation, for example Eq. 505 in D. Lidar's notes:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \tilde{\rho}(t) = - \text{Tr}_B \left( \left[ \tilde{H}(t), \int_0^t \mathrm{d}s \left[ \tilde{H}(s), \tilde{\rho}_{SB}(s) \right] \right] \right),$$
a change of variables $\tau = t-s$ is made with no reason for doing that.
However, in The Theory of Open Quantum Systems by Breuer and Petruccione, the reason is given that such substitution allows us to achieve dynamical semigroup form (see attached screenshot).
My question is: How does one achieve the semigroup property (which I know only from definition) by such change of variables and why is it important?

